# A variation in the construction of the tensor product of modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products

Let $A$ be a ring, $E$ a right $A$-module and $F$ a left $A$-module. Consider the free $\mathbf{Z}$-module $\mathbf{Z}^{(E\times F)}$ which comes with the injective canonical mapping $\phi:E\times F\rightarrow\mathbf{Z}^{(E\times F)},\,(x,y)\mapsto e_{x,y}$, where $e_{x,y}:=(\delta_{(x,y),z})_{z\in E\times F}$ for $(x,y)\in E\times F$.

Bourbaki defines the tensor product of $E$ and $F$ as the quotient $\mathbf{Z}$-module $(\mathbf{Z}^{(E\times F)})/C$, where $C$ is the submodule of $\mathbf{Z}^{(E\times F)}$ generated by the elements of the form $(e_{x_1+x_2,y}-e_{x_1,y}-e_{x_2,y})$, $(e_{x,y_1+y_2}-e_{x,y_1}-e_{x,y_2})$ and $e_{x\lambda,y}-e_{x,\lambda y}$ for $x,x_1,x_2\in E$ and $y,y_1,y_2\in F$ and $\lambda\in L$.

Elsewhere, I have seen the element of the form $ne_{x,y}-e_{xn,y}$, with $x\in E$, $y\in F$ and $n\in\mathbf{Z}$, added to the list above. Is this necessary? Why does Bourbaki leave it out?

Comment: It's a consequence that these will be also in $C$.

Comment: I suppose I would have to show that $ne_{x,y}-e_{xn,y}$ is a linear combination of the family of elements $(e_{x_1+x_2,y}-e_{x_1,y}-e_{x_2,y})$, correct?

Comment: Yes, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's indeed not necessary, as these elements will already be in $C$ even for Bourbaki's definition.

Specifically, for $n\ge 1$, use induction to see it (let $x_1=nx$ and $x_2=x$ in the induction step).

For $n\le 0$, use the rule $e_{x\lambda, \, y} -  e_{x,\, \lambda y} \in C$ with $\lambda=0$ and $\lambda=-1$.

Comment: Can you please clarify the induction step for me? I have $e_{x(n+1),y}-(n+1)e_{x,y}=e_{xn+x,y}-ne_{x,y}-e_{x,y}$. By induction hypothesis, $e_{xn,y}-ne_{x,y}\in C$. If I take $x_1=xn$ and $x_2=x$, then $e_{xn+x,y}-e_{xn,y}-e_{x,y}\in C$ by definition. But here I have $e_{xn,y}$ instead of $ne_{x,y}$. I am not sure how to utilize the induction hypothesis.

Comment: You're just there: $(e_{xn+x,\,y}-e_{xn, y} - e_{x,y})\, +\, (e_{xn, y} - ne_{x,y})\ \in C$.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again–I am not clear about where you got the rule "$e_{x\lambda,y}-\lambda e_{x,y}\in C$" from. I have $e_{x\lambda,y}-e_{x,\lambda y}\in C$ instead. Is that a typo?

Comment: Hmm.. You're right, it's my mistake. In this form they are present in the commutative setting only..

Comment: Last query (I promise): If $n<0$, then $0<-n$ and we have $e_{x(-n),y}-(-n)e_{x,y}=e_{(-x)n, y}+ne_{x,y}\in C$. How do you exactly propose to combine this with $e_{x\lambda,y}-e_{x,\lambda y}\in C$ (with $\lambda\in A$) to show that $e_{xn,y}-ne_{x,y}\in C$? Thank you for your help.

Comment: For $n>0$ use again the condition for addition: we have $e_{nx, y} - ne_{x,y}\in C$, and $e_{0, y}—e_{nx,y}-e_{-nx, y} \in C$, and also $e_{0,y}\in C$, hence also $e_{-nx,y}+ne_{x,y} \in C$